# JavaFX 2.x : How to move Line, Grid and X Ticks together?

Tags: grid, javafx-2, linechart

The code below plots a XYLineChart: by left mouse click and drag the plotted line can be translated left/right.

```
import javafx.application.Application; 
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty; 
import javafx.event.EventHandler;  
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis; 
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart; 
import javafx.stage.Stage; 
import javafx.scene.Scene; 
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart; 
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent; 
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
enter code here


public class GridMove extends Application {

    BorderPane pane;
    XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series();
    SimpleDoubleProperty rectinitX = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
    SimpleDoubleProperty rectX = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
    SimpleDoubleProperty rectY = new SimpleDoubleProperty();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis(1, 12, 1);
        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis(0.53000, 0.53910, 0.0005);

        xAxis.setAnimated(false);
        yAxis.setAnimated(false);

        yAxis.setTickLabelFormatter(new NumberAxis.DefaultFormatter(yAxis) {
            @Override
            public String toString(Number object) {
                return String.format("%7.5f", object);
            }
        });

        final LineChart<Number, Number> lineChart = new LineChart<Number, Number>(xAxis, yAxis);

        lineChart.setCreateSymbols(false);
        lineChart.setAlternativeRowFillVisible(false);
        lineChart.setAnimated(false);
        lineChart.setLegendVisible(false);

        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(1, 0.53185));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(2, 0.532235));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(3, 0.53234));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(4, 0.538765));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(5, 0.53442));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(6, 0.534658));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(7, 0.53023));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(8, 0.53001));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(9, 0.53589));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(10, 0.53476));

        pane = new BorderPane();
        pane.setCenter(lineChart);
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 800, 600);
        lineChart.getData().addAll(series1);

        stage.setScene(scene);

        scene.setOnMouseClicked(mouseHandler);
        scene.setOnMouseDragged(mouseHandler);
        scene.setOnMouseEntered(mouseHandler);
        scene.setOnMouseExited(mouseHandler);
        scene.setOnMouseMoved(mouseHandler);
        scene.setOnMousePressed(mouseHandler);
        scene.setOnMouseReleased(mouseHandler);
        stage.show();
    }
    EventHandler<MouseEvent> mouseHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {

            if (mouseEvent.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED) {
                rectinitX.set(mouseEvent.getX());
            } else if (mouseEvent.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED || mouseEvent.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVED) {
                LineChart<Number, Number> lineChart = (LineChart<Number, Number>) pane.getCenter();
                NumberAxis xAxis = (NumberAxis) lineChart.getXAxis();

                double Tgap = xAxis.getWidth() / (xAxis.getUpperBound() - xAxis.getLowerBound());
                double newXlower = xAxis.getLowerBound(), newXupper = xAxis.getUpperBound();
                double Delta = 0.3;

                if (mouseEvent.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED) {
                    if (rectinitX.get() < mouseEvent.getX()) {
                        newXlower = xAxis.getLowerBound() - Delta;
                        newXupper = xAxis.getUpperBound() - Delta;
                    } else if (rectinitX.get() > mouseEvent.getX()) {
                        newXlower = xAxis.getLowerBound() + Delta;
                        newXupper = xAxis.getUpperBound() + Delta;
                    }
                    xAxis.setLowerBound(newXlower);
                    xAxis.setUpperBound(newXupper);
                }
                rectinitX.set(mouseEvent.getX());
            }
        }
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

My questions are

1) Now by moving the Line left/right, Grid and X Ticks does not move: so, how to translate Line, Grid and X Ticks together?

2) Is it possible to accomplish this in JavaFx 2?

Thanks

**Edit** Nobody willing to help?

**Edit 2:** import statements added

**Edit 3:** Code improvements, now grid and line moves together. It only remains to move X axis ticks along with line and grid, and vertical grid lines are missing outside line range values

```
import java.util.Set;
import javafx.application.Application; 
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty; 
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;  
import javafx.scene.chart.Axis;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis; 
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart; 
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Series;
import javafx.stage.Stage; 
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene; 
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart; 
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent; 
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.shape.LineTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.MoveTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.Path;

public class GridMove extends Application {

BorderPane pane;

XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series();

SimpleDoubleProperty rectinitX = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
SimpleDoubleProperty rectX = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
SimpleDoubleProperty rectY = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
LineChart<Number, Number> lineChart;

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {

    final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis(1, 12, 1);
    final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis(0.53000, 0.53910, 0.0005);

    xAxis.setAnimated(false);
    yAxis.setAnimated(false);

    yAxis.setTickLabelFormatter(new NumberAxis.DefaultFormatter(yAxis) {
        @Override
        public String toString(Number object) {
            return String.format("%7.5f", object);
        }
    });

    lineChart = new LineChart<Number, Number>(xAxis, yAxis);

    lineChart.setCreateSymbols(false);
    lineChart.setAlternativeRowFillVisible(false);
    lineChart.setAnimated(false);
    lineChart.setLegendVisible(false);

    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(1, 0.53185));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(2, 0.532235));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(3, 0.53234));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(4, 0.538765));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(5, 0.53442));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(6, 0.534658));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(7, 0.53023));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(8, 0.53001));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(9, 0.53589));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(10, 0.53476));

    pane = new BorderPane();
    pane.setCenter(lineChart);
    Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 800, 600);
    lineChart.getData().addAll(series1);            

    stage.setScene(scene);

    scene.setOnMouseClicked(mouseHandler);
    scene.setOnMouseDragged(mouseHandler);
    scene.setOnMouseEntered(mouseHandler);
    scene.setOnMouseExited(mouseHandler);
    scene.setOnMouseMoved(mouseHandler);
    scene.setOnMousePressed(mouseHandler);
    scene.setOnMouseReleased(mouseHandler);
    stage.show();      
}
EventHandler<MouseEvent> mouseHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {

          if (mouseEvent.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED) {
            rectinitX.set(mouseEvent.getX());
        } else if (mouseEvent.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED || mouseEvent.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVED) {
            LineChart<Number, Number> lineChart = (LineChart<Number, Number>) pane.getCenter();
            NumberAxis xAxis = (NumberAxis) lineChart.getXAxis();

            double newXlower = xAxis.getLowerBound(), newXupper = xAxis.getUpperBound();
            double Delta = 0.3;

            if (mouseEvent.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED) {
                if (rectinitX.get() < mouseEvent.getX()) {
                    Delta *= -1;                    
                } 
                newXlower = xAxis.getLowerBound() + Delta;
                newXupper = xAxis.getUpperBound() + Delta;

                xAxis.setLowerBound(newXlower);
                xAxis.setUpperBound(newXupper);

                DoubleProperty p1 = xAxis.scaleXProperty();
                DoubleProperty p2 = xAxis.translateXProperty();

                double horizontalValueRange = xAxis.getUpperBound() - xAxis.getLowerBound();
                double horizontalWidthPixels = xAxis.getWidth();
                //pixels per unit
                double xScale = horizontalWidthPixels / horizontalValueRange;

                Set<Node> nodes = lineChart.lookupAll(".chart-vertical-grid-lines");
                for (Node n: nodes) {
                    Path p = (Path) n;
                    double currLayoutX = p.getLayoutX();
                    p.setLayoutX(currLayoutX + (Delta*-1) * xScale);
                }                    
                double lox = xAxis.getLayoutX();                                      
            }
            rectinitX.set(mouseEvent.getX());
        }
    }
};
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

Any help very much appreciated!

Comment: What specifically are you trying to accomplish? When I compile this (by the way, please include the imports next time, Eclipse/Netbeans are smart, but not that smart) and run it I see the graph moving with the tick marks *staying* with the plotted points. This makes sense. Are you looking to translate the graph (change all point values) or are you looking to move the graph. You're definitely moving it as is.

Comment: Hi Daniel: this code changes tick values while grid and tick marks stand still.
WHat's more, since X axis ranges in int values from 1 to 10, I shouldn't have decimal while moving left/right the line chart

Comment: A couple things: when I run it, the ticks stay static, but change number to reflect what you're looking at (correct behavior). Two, if you're concerned about the value of the ticks you need to set it via a whole value. Right now you're using the mouse event (double) which is setting it to a double. You would need to do some calculation to "snap" it over by sets of (1) but that shouldn't be too hard. If you're interested in scrolling the chart with the ticks you'll need to look deeper, that doesn't appear to be an "off the shelf" solution.

Comment: Hi Daniel thanks for your suggestions: yes you get straigth to the point, my interest is in scrolling (chart && ticks && grid) when LineChart is moved left/right, and this seems very tricky: hope to get some helps to solve this issue.

Comment: @ Adam Yes I did solve using this jfxutils https://github.com/gillius/jfxutils

Comment: I've managed to solve it by subclassing axis.. I raised a separate question. Is this the same issue you were having? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25383566/scrolling-xychart-with-javafx/25397836#25397836

Comment: Just having a look at jfxutils... Are you using StableTickAxis? http://gillius.org/jfxutils/docs/latest/org/gillius/jfxutils/chart/StableTicksAxis.html

Comment: Yes I am using StableTicksAxis and I found it very useful.

Answer (score 0):

This is rather a comment but somehow im too new to comment.

I would approach this by embedding your chart in a ScrollPane with invisible scrollbars and set the chart's y-axis opacity to 0 as well. If it is not feasable to load all chart data into memory you have to manage data fetching in scroll events etc.

Additionally you can use a standalone NumberAxis for your y-axis. You have to do the propper scaling and positioning by hand.